# select thresholds dynamically from sql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a range of data on search queries across diffrent merchants. 
I have a python script that 1st creates the head, torso & tail query sets from the main table in qsql, based on count(query) instances as 1000, 100 etc.

Since the number of merchants I my script runs of could have/not have queries that meet that threshold, the script does not log the "head.csv" "torso.csv" .. tail.csv always being produced. 
How can I break the queries into head, torso & tail groups by respecting the logic above.

I also tried ntile to break the groups by percentiles(33, 33, 33), but that skews both the head & torso, if a merchant has a very long tail.

Current :

```
# head
select  trim(query) as query, count(*) 
from my_merchant_table
-- other conditions & date range 
GROUP BY trim(query)
having count(*) >=1000 

#torso
select  trim(query) as query, count(*) 
from my_merchant_table
-- other conditions & date range 
GROUP BY trim(query)
having count(*) <1000  and count(*) >=100 

#tail
select  trim(query) as query, count(*) 
from my_merchant_table
-- other conditions & date range 
GROUP BY trim(query)
having count(*) <100 

# using ntile - but note that I have percentiles of "3" , 33.#% each, which introduces the skew
select trim(query), count(*) as query_count,
       ntile(3) over(order by query_count desc) AS group_ntile
     from my_merchant_table
    group by trim(query)
     order by query_count desc  limit 100;
```

Ideally the solution  can build on top of this -:

```
select trim(query), count(*) as query_count,
       ntile(100) over(order by query_count desc) AS group_ntile
     from my_merchant_table
      -- other conditions & date range 
    group by trim(query)
     order by query_count desc
```

This gives,

```
btrim   query_count group_ntile
q0  1277    1
q1  495 1
q2  357 1
q3  246 1
# so on till group_ntile =100 , while the query_count reduces.
```

**Question** : 
What is the best way for the logic, to make the overall logic merchant agnostic/no hard-coding the configs ?

**Note** : I am fetching the data in Redshift, the solution should be compatible to postgres 8.0 & redshift in particular.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please add some base to work on.

Comment: You ask for the definition of a sensible head and tail group while not telling us what sensible in your special application means. Using quantiles of the data certainly is one way. Another way would be to define the torso group as `mean +/- x*std`. There are a thousand other ways. So, before asking here, you have to ask yourself: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you from some programming language invokes its queries to process information. My recommendation in this regard is get all the records and apply a filter over they. Consider that if you queries the database where there are several operations over the data this would result that the response time of the application is affected.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the main challenge is to create the 'tiles' from a list of values, here is some sample code.  It takes the 13 provinces of Canada and breaks it into a requested number of groups.  It uses the province names, but numbers would work just as well.

```
SELECT * FROM Provinces ORDER BY province;  -- To see what we are working with
+---------------------------+
| province                  |
+---------------------------+
| Alberta                   |
| British Columbia          |
| Manitoba                  |
| New Brunswick             |
| Newfoundland and Labrador |
| Northwest Territories     |
| Nova Scotia               |
| Nunavut                   |
| Ontario                   |
| Prince Edward Island      |
| Quebec                    |
| Saskatchewan              |
| Yukon                     |
+---------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now for the code:

```
SELECT @n := COUNT(*),   -- Find total count (13)
       @j := 0.5,        -- 'trust me'
       @tiles := 3       -- The number of groupings
    FROM Provinces;

SELECT group_start
    FROM (
        SELECT
            IF((@j * @tiles) % @n < @tiles, province, NULL) AS group_start,
            @j := @j + 1
        FROM Provinces
        ORDER BY province
         ) x
    WHERE group_start IS NOT NULL;

+---------------------------+
| group_start               |
+---------------------------+
| Alberta                   |
| Newfoundland and Labrador |
| Prince Edward Island      |
+---------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With @tiles set to 4:

```
+---------------+
| group_start   |
+---------------+
| Alberta       |
| New Brunswick |
| Nova Scotia   |
| Quebec        |
+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It is reasonably efficient: 1 pass to count the number of rows, 1 pass to do the computation, 1 pass to filter out the non-break values.